# LNK2019 errors - how do I get rid of them?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt, visual-c++, linker-errors

Working on a qt project using msvc2008 compiler. I copied some functions from an example project that runs just fine in visual studio 2008, but now I'm getting LNK2019 errors. I've looked around, and they seem to caused by the compiler not finding some kinda declaration?

The errors are:

```
trackerwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: unsigned short const * __thiscall CPDIdev::GetLastResultStr(void)" (__imp_?GetLastResultStr@CPDIdev@@QAEPBGXZ) referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall trackerWindow::Connect(void)" (?Connect@trackerWindow@@AAE_NXZ)
```

and

```
trackerwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall CPDIbiterr::Parse(unsigned short *,unsigned long)const " (__imp_?Parse@CPDIbiterr@@QBEXPAGK@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall trackerWindow::SetupDevice(void)" (?SetupDevice@trackerWindow@@AAE_NXZ)
```

and

```
trackerwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall CPDIdev::StartPipeExport(unsigned short const *)" (__imp_?StartPipeExport@CPDIdev@@QAEHPBG@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall trackerWindow::SetupDevice(void)" (?SetupDevice@trackerWindow@@AAE_NXZ)
```

The CPDIdev class is from a library that the hardware I'm using uses, so i haven't written any of that code, and don't understand any of it.

I've got the following in the .pro file

```
INCLUDEPATH += D:\Patriot\Inc
LIBS += D:\Patriot\Lib\PDI.lib
```

and

```
#include "PDI.h"
```

in the header file (trackerwindow.h)... not really sure what declaration or include I'm missing...

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: getting rid of the messages is easy: just fix the problem (or `grep -v LNK2019`); I assume you meant to ask 'how to fix my link'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you are missing a import library, `.lib`.

Comment: PDI.lib was in the correct location, but I found another library in the same location PDIU.lib, so I thought what the hell, and I added it, finally realised I had to add the .dll file to my environment variables folder, and then voila, no more errors! Thanks!